# retrieve page source using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have to do retrieve the page source of a page with nodejs, but the page that I want to retrieve isn't always the same.

I have 2 files server.js that is listening and when he receive A connections he call load.js that retrive the sourse of a non defined page, my code is this:

server.js

```
var net = require('net');

var loadFb = require('./load.js');


var HOST = 'localhost';
var PORT = 9051;


// Create a server instance, and chain the listen function to it
// The function passed to net.createServer() becomes the event handler for the 'connection' event
// The sock object the callback function receives UNIQUE for each connection


net.createServer(function(sock) {

    // We have a connection - a socket object is assigned to the connection automatically
    console.log('CONNECTED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +':'+ sock.remotePort);

    // Add a 'data' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('data', function(data) {

        console.log('User request profile of: ' + data);
        // Write the data back to the socket, the client will receive it as data from the server


        //here I have to call test.js 

        //how


        sock.write(data);     
    });

    // Add a 'close' event handler to this instance of socket
    sock.on('close', function(data) {
        console.log('CLOSED: ' + sock.remoteAddress +' '+ sock.remotePort);
    });

}).listen(PORT, HOST);


console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

the other file is this:

```
 var https = require('https');


 var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/dario.vettore',
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
    var pageData = "";
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      pageData += chunk;
      //console.log(pageData);
      return pageData;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){
      //response.send(pageData)
    });
  });
```

How can I ask from the first file (server.js) to the second file to retrive for it the page source from the second file, But the page that I want to get the source can change isn't always the same..

Answer (score 0):

In your second file (I'm assuming that's the one named `loadFb.js`), you want to export a function, instead of calling the code right away.

Node caches its modules so when you `require()` them, the code only gets run once.

The second file should look something like this:

```
var https = require('https');

module.exports = function(path, callback) {
  var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: path,
    method: 'GET'
  };

  var req = https.get(options, function(res) {
    var pageData = "";
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      pageData += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function(){
      callback(pageData);
    });
  });
};
```

Then in your first file, you would access it like this:

```
loadJs('/dario.vettore', function(pageData) {
  console.log(pageData);
});
```

This way you can execute the module code many times, with different paths.

Comment: Great!!! Sorry for my english, and I am not able to use nodejs... I will try as soon as possible your solutions!!!!